# How to copy a row range from one column to others in a column oriented c# datatable?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable

To my understanding the entries of a datatable are usually row oriented where the columns have a certain meaning and the rows indicate different datasets.
This is also why the actual data is added with DataTable.Rows.Add()
In my case the columns are considered one dataset and I need to extract data from these columns for use in other areas.

I am using a combination of LINQ and Lambda expressions to get the data of one complete column:

```
int curCol = 4;
int maxRows = 55;
byte[] values = new byte[maxRows];
values = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select<DataRow, byte>(row => Convert.ToByte(row[curCol])).ToArray();
```

But this is where my luck with LINQ and Lambda ends.
I try to implement a copy routine to select columns different from the source but having the same value in a certain row. Then I select a range of rows to be copied to all the other matching columns. Here is an example how this works with for and if statements:

```
const int numCols = 10;
int curCol = 2;
int searchRow = 1;
int startRow = 3;
int numRows = 25;
byte val = (byte)dt.Rows[searchRow][curCol]; 
// iterate through all columns
for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
{
    // look for "other" columns with the same value in the searchRow of interest
    if (col != curCol && val == (byte)dt.Rows[searchRow][col])
    {
        // iterate through the given row range (startRow and numRows)
        for (int row = startRow; row < startRow+numRows; row++)
        {
            // copy from current column
            dt.Rows[row][col] = dt.Rows[row][curCol];
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a nicer, more efficient way to implement this Using LINQ and Lambda expressions?

Example Data

```
1 2 3 4 ... // cols 0 .. 3 in row 0
5 5 6 6 ... // cols 0 .. 3 in row 1
0 0 1 0 ... // ...
7 0 8 0 ...
9 0 9 0 ...
. . . .
```

Expected Result

```
1 2 3 4 ...
5 5 6 6 ... // value in col 3 is equal to value in col 2
0 0 1 0 ...
7 0 8 8 ... // value from col 2 copied to col 3
9 0 9 9 ... // value from col 2 copied to col 3
. . . .
```

I hope this makes it easier to understand. Column 2 and 3 are grouped/linked by their value in row 1 and since column 2 is the source other values from a selected row range should be copied over to the linked colums.
Just to make that clear. The If/For implementation above does exactly this. I was just hoping for a LINQ/Lambda shortcut or another more efficient way of execution.

Comment: not sure that i understood your requrement. can you please give and example of input datatable and expected output?

Comment: If you only want to copy *cells* from one column to another, then it's a single loop over rows where you just `row[x] = row[y]`. If not, then please explain the problem better (with example or input data and wanted result).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            const int numCols = 10;
        int curCol = 4;
        int searchRow = 1;
        int startRow = 3;
        int numRows = 25;
        int hashVal = dt.Rows[searchRow][curCol].GetHashCode();
        var thisValue = dt.Rows[searchRow][curCol];
        //iterate cols and rows
        for(int c = 0; c < numCols; c++)
        {
            for(int r = startRow; r < startRow + numRows; r++)
            {
                int thisHash = dt.Rows[r][c].GetHashCode();
                if (thisHash == hashVal)
                {
                    dt.Rows[r][c] = thisValue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Nothing ground-shaking. What I don't understand, though, is that you seem to be finding matching values in order to copy matching values - by default, if the value is already equal to the source row/col, then why does it need to be copied (because it's already equal)? Perhaps you're simplifying for demonstration purposes, but I'm not seeing a need for this...

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but this changes the behavior of my implementation which is not what I want. I would like to look always in the same row as the searchRow over all columns and not each individual cell value.